# How to most efficiently join two tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

I have two tables which store Amounts and Adjustments for LineItemTypes of a specific ReportingPeriod.  I am looking for the most efficient way to query the Amount and Adjustment for each ReportingPeriod/LineItemType combination that exists across the two tables.

Schemas are present below:

**@ReportingPeriodComposition (1030 rows - Table Variable)**

```
Src int,
GroupReportingPeriodId int,
ReportingPeriodId int,
ClientId int,
PeriodDate date,
...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Src, ReportingPeriodId)
```

**Amount (~30,000,000 rows)**

```
ReportingPeriodId int,
LineItemTypeId smallint,
Amount decimal,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ReportingPeriodId, LineItemTypeId)
```

**Adjustment (~180,000 rows)**

```
ReportingPeriodId int,
LineItemTypeId smallint,
Amount decimal,
Comment nvarchar(2500),
...
AdjustmentId int,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (AdjustmentId),
UNIQUE KEY CLUSTERED (ReportingPeriodId, LineItemTypeId)
```

I would like to select the Amounts and Adjustments by unique ReportingPeriodId/LineItemTypeId yielding the following result set:

```
| ReportingPeriodId | LineItemTypeId | Amount | Adjustment |
```

Currently I am using the following query, but I am curious to see if anyone has thoughts on how this can be done more efficiently.  All suggestions welcome!

```
SELECT
    rpc.ReportingPeriodId,
    COALESCE(a.LineItemTypeId, adj.LineItemTypeId) LineItemTypeId,
    a.Amount,
    adj.Amount Adjustment
FROM @ReportingPeriodComposition rpc
LEFT JOIN Watchlist.risk.Amount a
    ON rpc.ReportingPeriodId = a.ReportingPeriodId
LEFT JOIN Watchlist.risk.Adjustment adj
    ON rpc.ReportingPeriodId = adj.ReportingPeriodId
    AND (a.ReportingPeriodId IS NULL OR a.LineItemTypeId = adj.LineItemTypeId)
WHERE
    Src = @Src
    AND (a.LineItemTypeId IS NOT NULL OR adj.LineItemTypeId IS NOT NULL)
```

Note that the @Src variable is necessary to determine which source values we need to pull from the @ReportingPeriodComposition table variable.  The query results in ~138,000 rows:

- 1 row has both an Amount and an Adjustment although this number may vary depending on the ReportingPeriodComposition
- 0 rows have only an Adjustment although this condition is not guaranteed

---

**Execution Plan XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.0.4064.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="9" StatementEstRows="104.769" StatementId="5" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.343989" StatementText="SELECT&#xD;&#xA;    rpc.ReportingPeriodId,&#xD;&#xA;    COALESCE(a.LineItemTypeId, adj.LineItemTypeId) LineItemTypeId,&#xD;&#xA;    a.Amount,&#xD;&#xA; adj.Amount Adjustment&#xD;&#xA;FROM @ReportingPeriodComposition rpc&#xD;&#xA;LEFT JOIN Rating.risk.Amount a&#xD;&#xA;   ON rpc.ReportingPeriodId = a.ReportingPeriodId&#xD;&#xA;LEFT JOIN Rating.risk.Adjustment adj&#xD;&#xA;  ON rpc.ReportingPeriodId = adj.ReportingPeriodId&#xD;&#xA;  AND (a.ReportingPeriodId IS NULL OR a.LineItemTypeId = adj.LineItemTypeId)&#xD;&#xA;WHERE&#xD;&#xA; Src = @Src&#xD;&#xA;    AND (a.LineItemTypeId IS NOT NULL OR adj.LineItemTypeId IS NOT NULL)" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x425781A4C1D20919" QueryPlanHash="0xF3E9DD0ADAD04044">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="5" CompileCPU="5" CompileMemory="424">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="31" EstimateCPU="1.04769E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="104.769" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.343989">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="Amount" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="Amount" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
              </OutputList>
              <ComputeScalar>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN [Rating].[risk].[Amount].[LineItemTypeId] as [a].[LineItemTypeId] IS NOT NULL THEN [Rating].[risk].[Amount].[LineItemTypeId] as [a].[LineItemTypeId] ELSE [Rating].[risk].[Adjustment].[LineItemTypeId] as [adj].[LineItemTypeId] END">
                      <IF>
                        <Condition>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="IS NOT">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Condition>
                        <Then>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Then>
                        <Else>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Else>
                      </IF>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="33" EstimateCPU="9.21971E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="104.769" LogicalOp="Filter" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Filter" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.343979">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="Amount" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="Amount" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="137631" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Filter StartupExpression="false">
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="33" EstimateCPU="0.000437936" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="104.769" LogicalOp="Left Outer Join" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.343886">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="Amount" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="Amount" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="137647" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <NestedLoops Optimized="false" WithUnorderedPrefetch="true">
                        <OuterReferences>
                          <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                          <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                          <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                        </OuterReferences>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="26" EstimateCPU="0.000437936" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="104.769" LogicalOp="Left Outer Join" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00711828">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="Amount" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="137647" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                            <OuterReferences>
                              <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                            </OuterReferences>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="0">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1030" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Table="[@ReportingPeriodComposition]" Index="[PK__#6FDF7DF__F9ABEE3F71C7C670]" Alias="[rpc]" />
                                <SeekPredicates>
                                  <SeekPredicateNew>
                                    <SeekKeys>
                                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                        <RangeColumns>
                                          <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="Src" />
                                        </RangeColumns>
                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@Src]">
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Column="@Src" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                      </Prefix>
                                    </SeekKeys>
                                  </SeekPredicateNew>
                                </SeekPredicates>
                              </IndexScan>
                            </RelOp>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="22" EstimateCPU="0.000272246" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="104.769" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00339725" TableCardinality="29974300">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="Amount" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="137631" ActualEndOfScans="1030" ActualExecutions="1030" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="Amount" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Index="[PK_Amount]" Alias="[a]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                <SeekPredicates>
                                  <SeekPredicateNew>
                                    <SeekKeys>
                                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                        <RangeColumns>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                        </RangeColumns>
                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="@ReportingPeriodComposition.[ReportingPeriodId] as [rpc].[ReportingPeriodId]">
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                      </Prefix>
                                    </SeekKeys>
                                  </SeekPredicateNew>
                                </SeekPredicates>
                              </IndexScan>
                            </RelOp>
                          </NestedLoops>
                        </RelOp>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="18" EstimateCPU="0.000165111" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="103.769" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="7" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.33565" TableCardinality="178911">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="Amount" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="137647" ActualExecutions="137647" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="Amount" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Index="[IX_Adjustment_ReportingPeriodId_LineItemTypeId]" Alias="[adj]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                            <SeekPredicates>
                              <SeekPredicateNew>
                                <SeekKeys>
                                  <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                    <RangeColumns>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                    </RangeColumns>
                                    <RangeExpressions>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="@ReportingPeriodComposition.[ReportingPeriodId] as [rpc].[ReportingPeriodId]">
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Table="@ReportingPeriodComposition" Alias="[rpc]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </RangeExpressions>
                                  </Prefix>
                                </SeekKeys>
                              </SeekPredicateNew>
                            </SeekPredicates>
                            <Predicate>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Rating].[risk].[Amount].[ReportingPeriodId] as [a].[ReportingPeriodId] IS NULL OR [Rating].[risk].[Amount].[LineItemTypeId] as [a].[LineItemTypeId]=[Rating].[risk].[Adjustment].[LineItemTypeId] as [adj].[LineItemTypeId]">
                                <Logical Operation="OR">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="ReportingPeriodId" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Logical>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Predicate>
                          </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                      </NestedLoops>
                    </RelOp>
                    <Predicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Rating].[risk].[Amount].[LineItemTypeId] as [a].[LineItemTypeId] IS NOT NULL OR [Rating].[risk].[Adjustment].[LineItemTypeId] as [adj].[LineItemTypeId] IS NOT NULL">
                        <Logical Operation="OR">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="IS NOT">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Amount]" Alias="[a]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="IS NOT">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Rating]" Schema="[risk]" Table="[Adjustment]" Alias="[adj]" Column="LineItemTypeId" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Predicate>
                  </Filter>
                </RelOp>
              </ComputeScalar>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@Src" ParameterRuntimeValue="(2)" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Any chance you could show the query plan it produces - from the description and schema shown, nothing would appear 'obviously' wrong

Comment: I can do that.  How would you like me to show that?

Comment: XML or Graphic, either would work

Comment: @Andrew I have added the execution plan.  I stripped out the other batches in the sequence so hopefully it's still in a meaningful state.  I would have included the full plan but unfortunately that would put me well over the character limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing particularily bad within the query plan that you have posted that I can see - I suspect SQL is making the right choices. The only thing I could spot which is slightly dodgy is that the query plan estimates and the actual number of rows returned are quite far apart - which indiates the stats are not entirely up to date - you could forcibly update the stats and see if it continues to use the same query plan.

If you are having issue with inconsistent performance, on a dev box clear the query plan cache and generate the query plan for a `@SRC` value that would produce very few rows, then clear the plan cache and generate the query plan for a `@SRC` value that would produce a very large amount of rows to be returned. If the query plans are the same you are ok, if they are different then you may need to use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint. This sometimes happens on parameterized queries where the first run of them determines the plan that sits in cache - and until that plan ages out, subsequent runs of the query use the same plan.

You would have to now provide more information about what specific problem you are encountering / looking to solve by having this reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a [JOIN HINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx)?

From MSDN:

> LOOP | HASH | MERGE Specifies that the join in the query should use
>   looping, hashing, or merging. Using LOOP |HASH | MERGE JOIN enforces a
>   particular join between two tables. LOOP cannot be specified together
>   with RIGHT or FULL as a join type.
>
> REMOTE Specifies that the join operation is performed on the site of
>   the right table. This is useful when the left table is a local table
>   and the right table is a remote table. REMOTE should be used only when
>   the left table has fewer rows than the right table.
>
> If the right table is local, the join is performed locally. If both
>   tables are remote but from different data sources, REMOTE causes the
>   join to be performed on the site of the right table. If both tables
>   are remote tables from the same data source, REMOTE is not required.
>
> REMOTE cannot be used when one of the values being compared in the
>   join predicate is cast to a different collation using the COLLATE
>   clause.
>
> REMOTE can be used only for INNER JOIN operations.

In your case you may be able to use a LOOP join since you are dealing with a LEFT join.  Other then that your query looks fine, do you have indexes on the columns that you are filtering on?

Your amount table does have a lot of rows - but I've seen databases with much more.  What is the hardware you are working with ?

For an example of how LOOP JOIN can be used and showed a particular optimization see this [article](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Per/Archive/2008/3/LOOP-JOIN-and-other-fun-query-optimizations/).  But it all depends on the type of query when using a join hint.  It may not be applicable and should be a last resort option in your case.

Comment: The query optimizer is choosing to perform Nested Loops for the Left Outer Joins.  98% of the case is the Clustered Index Seek on IX_Adjustment_ReportingPeriodId_LineItemTypeId.

1 Actual # of Rows, 137647 # of Executions, 104.769 Estimated # of Executions

Answer (score 0):

I would try replacing the `@table_variable` with a `#temp` table so that SQL Server has more accurate statistics to play with.

Currently it assumes the table variable will return 1 row and chooses a nested loops plan. You may get a different one if it can take account of the actual table cardinalities.